# Mongo find if any possible field in array of subdocuments has value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm running an `aggregate` on a `Collection` and am using a lookup to another child `Collection`.

Each child may or may not have a field (`foo`) that can contain a `String`.

I'd like to `project` a `Boolean` for if at least 1 of these `field`s has a `String` for any of the child `subdocuments`.

So I can have something like

```
db.Parent.aggregate([
  {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'Children', 
      'localField': '_id', 
      'foreignField': 'parentId', 
      'as': 'CHILDREN'
    }
  }, {
     childHasFoo: {
         "$CHILDREN" : {$elemMatch: {foo: {$ne: ''}}}
     }
}
]
```

You can see my projection for `childHasFoo` . I'm thinking I can use `$elemMatch` or `$anyElementTrue`. Remember, `foo` may not exist on an/all of the children `subdocuments` either. So that needs to be taken into account.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- iterate loop of `CHILDREN` array using `$map` array operator,
- check your condition using `$ne` this will return boolean value
- `$anyElementTrue` to check is any element has true

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      childHasFoo: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
          $map: {
            input: "$CHILDREN",
            in: { $ne: ["$$this.foo", ""] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

Second option to more accurate condition,

- `$trim` to remove white space from string
- `$not` and `$in` to check is string empty "" or `null` then false otherwise true

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      childHasFoo: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
          $map: {
            input: "$CHILDREN",
            in: {
              $not: {
                $in: [
                  { $trim: { input: "$$this.foo" } },
                  ["", null]
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: More accurate soln is what worked, thanks! Is there a reason you're using `addFields` instead of just adding to the `projection`, or was this just for demo's sake?

Comment: Also, any idea how expensive this operation is? Or - will it not really matter?

Comment: the projection is `find()` property, you are using `aggregate()` method so you can use anyone stage from `$addFields`, `$project`, `$set` there are different approaches, yes little expensive but its ok if you have limited elements in array `CHILDREN`.